# "Compiler Bug", "Segmentation Fault 11" On Custom View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-animation, ios5

I'm having a very weird problem, that I think I know why I'm getting it but I can't seem to think of a fix. I am convinced there is no compiler bug here. I have had many of those and all of them occurred because of my faulty code.

Basically, I have a view controller called UnlockKeyboardViewController that inherits from UIViewController, and a custom view (inheriting directly from UIView) called UnlockKeyboard. The header for UnlockKeyboard looks like this:

```
@interface UnlockKeyboard : UIView
{
    NSArray *buttons;
    NSArray *passcodeFields;

    UIImage *buttonBackgroundImage;
    UIImage *buttonBackgroundHighlightedImage;
    UIImage *middleButtonBackgroundImage;
    UIImage *middleButtonBackgroundImageHighlighted;
    UIImage *screenBackgroundImage;

    UIImage *infoViewContainerImage;
    UIImage *keypadViewContainerImage;
    UIImage *passcodeFieldsContainerImage;

    UIImage *infoViewImage;
    UIImage *passcodeViewImage;

    UIView *infoViewContainer;
    UIView *keypadViewContainer;
    UIView *passcodeFieldsContainer;

    UIView *infoView;
    UIView *keypadView;
    UIView *passcodeFieldsView;

    UIView *infoToDisplayView; //The view the programmer passes to show in infoView.
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *buttonBackgroundImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *buttonBackgroundHighlightedImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *screenBackgroundImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *keypadViewBackgroundImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *infoViewContainerImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *keypadViewContainerImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *passcodeFieldsContainerImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *infoViewImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIImage *passcodeViewImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *infoToDisplayView;

//Properties for container views.
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *infoViewContainer;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *keypadViewContainer;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *passcodeFieldsContainer;

@end
```

The UnlockKeyboardViewController implementation looks like this so far:

```
@implementation UnlockKeyboardViewController
-(id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.view = [[UnlockKeyboard alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        self.view.keypadViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 261, 320, 200);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

This is were my problem gets interesting. Whenever I try to compile, the Terminal (this is a jailbreak app, so no Xcode) gives me the following error:

```
In function ‘void __-[UnlockKeyboardViewController viewDidAppear:]_block_invoke_1(void*)’:
Segmentation fault: 11
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <URL:http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter> for instructions.
```

BUT, this error only appears when I have this line in:

```
self.view.keypadViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 261, 320, 200);
```

If I don't that line in my animation block, the compiler won't give me that error and it wil compile just fine. Although, no matter were I put this line, I always get segmentation line 11.

I THINK this may have something to do with the fact that UIView doesn't have a member called keypadViewContainer, although UnlockKeyboard has that property and is a subclass of UIView. I believe this is happening because the compiler can't actually see the class hierarchy between UIView and UnlockKeyboard.

If I'm right, I have no idea of how to go around the problem. Been thinking for a while. Any input to help me solve this problem will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a nib file for your view controller? If not, the base implementation of `loadView` would set the `view` property of your `UnlockKeyboardViewController` to a regular `UIView`, negating what you did in `init` (you shouldn't really load the `view` in `init` anyway).

Comment: You say "no Xcode"; what compiler are you using?

Comment: omz: I think you are right. Should I try to do this assignment in loadView then? I'm not using any nibs or anything. This is pure code because I'm not using XCode. I Don't use XCode for Jailbreaks apps.

benzado: Still using GCC. I'm just not using XCode as my IDE.

Comment: Yes, `loadView` is the proper place to load your view.

Comment: Well, just tried moving the initialisation to loadView and it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should only set a view controller's view property in its `loadView` method:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UnlockKeyboard alloc] init];
}
```

This will trigger other methods, such as `viewDidLoad`, that will expect the object to have been full initialized. Moral of the story: don't set the `view` property until the controller asks you to.

Then, in your `viewDidAppear:` method, casing the `view` property into the specific subclass you are using should avoid any warnings and hopefully also that weird compiler crash:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
    UnlockKeyboard *ukView = (UnlockKeyboard *)self.view;
    ukView.keypadViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 261, 320, 200);
```

The code as you have written it should have triggered a compiler warning, because the property `keypadViewContainer` isn't defined on `UIView` (the type of the expression `self.view`).

The type cast is admittedly a little bit ugly, but it's necessary since the view controller is a generic parent class and doesn't know what kind of view it is controlling. You may find it useful to define a property that eliminates the need to do the cast all the time:

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly) UnlockKeyboard *unlockKeyboardView;
```

And the corresponding method:

```
- (UnlockKeyboard *)unlockKeyboardView
{
    return self.view;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is supposed to generate a warning. Theos gave me the habit of treating warnings as errors so the compiler is bugging out before getting a chance to give me the warnings. That being said, I'm not sure about this solution, since UK is supposed to be the main view for this controller (IE, we are not assigning anything to self.view). Regardless, I will give it a shot, but the other methods (viewDidLoad, etc) are the ones that worry me shall this work.

Comment: Blah, maybe I should just create everything using the controller instead of creating the view's subview's in the view itself... Very likely that will fix this problem.

Comment: @Sergio I elaborated on my answer a bit, hopefully addressing some of your concerns.

Comment: I solved everything by just using the controller. My original idea was to create a big UIView that will be the whole UnlockKeyboard. That was just going to cause me problems so I decided to change it. Only problem I'm having know is that the animation doesn't take place (unless I am forgetting something), but I solved the first problem. Marking your answer as the chosen since you enlightened me to use the controller. Thanks again.